# C++ Hotkey to run function

Tags: winapi, hotkeys

Hey looking to assign <kbd>F1</kbd> as a hotkey to run a function. I have a windows 32 project with a Form, however the form will be in the background and not the active window when I press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Is there a way to code a hotkey or shortcut so when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> it will run that function even if the Form1 isn't active?

Comment: There's no thing like a _hotkey_ in standard c++.

Comment: Think you need a global hook to do that. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9149702/4581301

Comment: I would look into how AutoHotKey does this. It's free. And it uses a bunch of dll calls, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`RegisterHotKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

It allows you to define a system-wide hot key. When the hot key is pressed, you will receive a `WM_HOTKEY` message even if your window is not active.